# mydriver.sys did not appear in the selection tab under "software device" in HLK studio

Tags: windows, driver, digital-signature, hlk

I wrote a driver, mydriver, which is based on winio(https://github.com/starofrainnight/winio) to directly access I/O ports and physical memory. I'd like to upload the 64-bit version of mydriver to Microsoft to have it crossed signed to meet driver signing requirements. I installed mydriver successfully using the command shown below:

```
pnputil.exe -i -a mydriver.inf
```

However, mydriver.sys did not appear in the selection tab under "software device" in HLK studio. The mydriver.inf is shown as below.

```
[Version] 
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$" 
Class=System 
ClassGuid={4d36e97d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} 
Provider=%ManufacturerName% 
DriverVer = 08/24/2023,0.0.0.3 
CatalogFile=mydriver.cat  

[DestinationDirs] 
DefaultDestDir = 12   

[SourceDisksNames] 
1 = %DiskName%,,,""  

[SourceDisksFiles]   

[Manufacturer] 
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NTamd64  

[Standard.NTamd64]   

[Strings] 
ManufacturerName="" ;TODO: Replace with your manufacturer name 
ClassName="" 
DiskName="mydriver Source Disk"
```